# Javascript email validation failing on a valid email address?

Tags: javascript, function, validation, email

I seem to be unable to get a basic javascript email validation function to work correctly. It keeps returning that the email address is invalid even when using a real email address.

Could someone please point me in the right direction as i couldn't find the problem on any other similar SO posts. I don't think it's the function itself, but perhaps how i am calling it? I have posted the code below.

```js
// E-mail validation via regular expression - taken from SO solution
// Needs to be accessible for other Forms to use
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
  return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};


// Validate Contact Form
function validate_contact(evt) {

  var error = '';

  // Set Veriables
  var email = document.getElementById("contact_email");



  // Validate Other Fields Here
  //  - Removed for Example -


  // Validate Email Address
  if (!isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
    error += '- Please enter a valid Email Address.\n';
  }


  // Show Error Notice
  if (error != '') {
    error = 'The form has not been completed correctly, please check the following:\n\n' + error;
    alert(error);
    evt.preventDefault(); // Stop the event

  } else {
    // Proceed
  }
}




// Get reference DOM elements
var contact_form = document.getElementById("contact_form");

// Set up event - Contact Form Validation
contact_form.addEventListener("submit", validate_contact);

// Set up event - Other Form Validation
//other_form.addEventListener("submit", validate_other);
```

```html
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" id="contact_email" name="email" value="">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Your regex is bad - the backslash character is used as a delimiter and must be doubled up when it's needed literally.  You have a bunch of `\uXXXX` constructs - they need to become `\\uXXXX`.  See [this](https://regex101.com/r/ZZWUQd/1)

Comment: @James just a note - even with the escapes, the regex isn't really correct. It won't allow non-English characters, for example. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/ZZWUQd/2) is a very quick check I did with some "strange" emails. Well, at least it recognises that the name part can be quoted.

Comment: Just use `type="email"` instead of text to let the native browser email validation kick in and and an optional require attribute if you need it. Then remove all javascript code :D You will also get the `@` sign on software keyboard like on phones ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do some basic debugging. **Look** at the contents of the variables you are testing.

```
var email = document.getElementById("contact_email");
```

The value of `email` is the **input element**, not the text entered into it. For that you need to read its `.value` property.

Solution is to add ".value"

```
var email = document.getElementById("contact_email").value;
```

Comment: @JamesParry `document.getElementById("name*)` will give you the *HTML element* itself, so your variable `email` stores that. You cannot test it successfully against the regex, as it's not a string. You need to get the value from inside the input element either by `document.getElementById("name").value` or `email.value` or some other fashion.